# How to make second week of every saturday in red using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have got a doubt in Calendar control. I don't know how to select all the second week of Saturday in a year. I have to use Calendar control. Its `ForeColor` should be Red. Should I use `bool` flag for selecting second week of Saturday?

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday")
        {
            flag = true;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        if(!flag)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below:

```
bool IsSecondSaturdayInMonth(DateTime date)
{
    // 2nd Saturday cannot be before the 8th day or after 14th of the month...
    if (date.Day < 8 || date.Day > 14)
    {
      return false;
    }

    return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday;

 }
```

You can then use as such:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsSecondSaturdayInMonth(e.Day.Date))
    {
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use the flag (bool) variable. Pertinent to your case (i.e. to highlight all second and subsequent Sat), use the sample code snippet following (re:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday" && e.Day.Date.Day > 7)
    {
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan Sajjad! Rgds,

Comment: This will get all Saturday's other than the first one of the month.  This is not what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //try this....
        if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth)//check whether the day is in selected month or not
        {               
            // 2nd Saturday must be before the 15th day and after 7th of the month...,so check the condition
            if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday && e.Day.Date.Day > 7 && e.Day.Date.Day < 15)
            {
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;//set the Day in Red colour
                e.Cell.ToolTip = "Second Saturday";//set the tooltip as 'Second saturday'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer describing your solution